# How to embed a live video - connection failed application rejected connection

Tags: video

I tried many ways to get the correct path to embed this live streaming video in this url: "http://www.turbotv.in/mazhavil-manorama-live/"  to my website, but couldn't do it. 
JW player says "connection failed: application rejected connection"

Now i need someone who knows this properly to find out the correct embedding code out of this website
http://www.turbotv.in/mazhavil-manorama-live/ , so that i could embed the live video to my website.

Now need an early solution to this. An early reply always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The URL played by JWPlayer on that site is provided as a parameter to the JWPlayer embed code in HTML:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="
       netstreambasepath=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.turbotv.in%2Fmazhavil-manorama-live%2F&amp;
       id=jwplayer-2&amp;
       flashplayer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.turbotv.in%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fjw-player-plugin-for-wordpress%2Fplayer%2Fplayer.swf&amp;
       autostart=true&amp;
       repeat=none&amp;
       shuffle=false&amp;
       bufferlength=5&amp;
       smoothing=true&amp;
       stretching=exactfit&amp;
       wmode=opaque&amp;
       mute=false&amp;
       volume=30&amp;
       mediaid=538&amp;
       image=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.turbotv.in%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F09%2FMazhavil-Manorama-Logo.jpg&amp;
       streamer=rtmp%3A%2F%2F37.130.230.101%2Fbase2%2F&amp;
       file=maha2.stream&amp;
       controlbar.position=bottom&amp;
       playlist.position=none&amp;
       playlist.size=180&amp;
       display.icons=true&amp;
       dock=false">
```

The values are url-encoded and on top of that HTML-encoded, of course. The key parameters you are interested are "streamer" and "file" - these are the parameters for the RTMP streaming. You can see the [JWPlayer documentation](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12536/configuration-options) for their semantics.

Of course, you will also need to make sure you have the publisher's permission to embed the video channel on your website. But I guess this is off-topic for StackOverflow.